# How to call ObjectSpace.each_object with C API without rb_string_eval?

Tags: c, ruby, api, objectspace, funcall

I'm currently trying to get all the instances of a class and I wanted to use `ObjectSpace.each_object` to achieve that.

Here is my actual code in C :

```
ruby_init();
int ruby_state = 0;
rb_string_eval_protect("def my_func ; ObjectSpace.each_object(Klass) { |x| x.do_something } ; end", &ruby_state);
ruby_cleanup(ruby_state);
```

However, I don't know if it's really a good thing to do. I wanted to use `rb_funcall` instead, which is maybe a cleaner way to do it.

My questions are :

- Is it better to use `rb_funcall` than `string_eval`? (I think so because of parser)
- How can I retrieve the `ObjectSpace` module in C API since `rb_mObjectSpace` doesn't seem to exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do that. It's using `rb_const_get`.

Here is the code now:

```
VALUE rb_mObjSpace = rb_const_get(rb_cObject, rb_intern("ObjectSpace"));
```

The module was already defined in `gc.c` but was not public. The only way to access to the module seems to be *via* `rb_const_get` (or to modify gc.c and build ruby, but no one wants to do that).